# Arrange the html text inside flag ( HighStock)

Tags: html, highcharts

I have been trying to arrange the text inside the flag element for highstock similar to image below but been struggling for too long. 
Was wondering if this is possible and how

[image: The arrange of the text inside the flag]

Updated in jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/wj9vvq6o/

```
$(function () {
    $.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=usdeur.json&callback=?', function (data) {

        // Create the chart
        $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {


            rangeSelector : {
                selected : 1
            },

            title : {
                text : 'USD to EUR exchange rate'
            },

            yAxis : {
                title : {
                    text : 'Exchange rate'
                }
            },

            series : [{
                name : 'USD to EUR',
                data : data,
                id : 'dataseries',
                tooltip : {
                    valueDecimals: 4
                }
            }, {
                type : 'flags',
                data : [{
                    x : Date.UTC(2011, 1, 22),
                    title : 'A',
                    text : 'Shape: "squarepin"'
                }, {
                    x : Date.UTC(2011, 3, 28),
                    title : 'Test Name goes here <br> Test 2 goes here',
                    text : 'Shape: "squarepin"'
                }],
                onSeries : 'dataseries',
                shape : 'squarepin',
                width : 140
            }, {
                type : 'flags',
                data : [{
                    x : Date.UTC(2011, 2, 1),
                    title : 'B',
                    text : 'Shape: "circlepin"'
                }, {
                    x : Date.UTC(2011, 3, 1),
                    title : 'B',
                    text : 'Shape: "circlepin"'
                }],
                shape : 'circlepin',
                width : 16
            }, {
                type : 'flags',
                data : [{
                    x : Date.UTC(2011, 2, 10),
                    title : 'C',
                    text : 'Shape: "flag"'
                }, {
                    x : Date.UTC(2011, 3, 11),
                    title : 'C',
                    text : 'Shape: "flag"'
                }],
                color : Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0], // same as onSeries
                fillColor : Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
                onSeries : 'dataseries',
                width : 16,
                style : {// text style
                    color : 'white'
                },
                states : {
                    hover : {
                        fillColor : '#395C84' // darker
                    }
                }
            }]
        });
    });
});
```

This is all i have managed - i need to add the number 100 beside it

Comment: Can you post the code you're working with?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set a useHTML flag in series object. Then arrange your content by HTML elements and CSS styles.

series:

```
       {
            useHTML:true,
            dataLabels:{
                useHTML:true,
            },
            type : 'flags',
            data : [{
                x : Date.UTC(2011, 1, 22),
                title : 'A',
                text : 'Shape: "squarepin"'
            }, {
                x : Date.UTC(2011, 3, 28),
                title : '<span style="text-align:right;width:100%;display:block;">Test Name goes here </span>100 <br><span style="text-align:right;width:100%;display:block;">Test 2 goes here</span>',
                text : 'Shape: "squarepin"'
            }],
            onSeries : 'dataseries',
            shape : 'squarepin',
            width : 140
        },
```

Simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/wj9vvq6o/4/

Comment: Yeah - i figured it out 2 days back used this
'<div style="border:1px solid black;width:20px;height:20px;text-align:center;border-radius:50%;color:white;background-color:green;position:absolute;margin-top:5px;font-weight:bold">43</div><div style="letter-spacing:1px;margin-left:23px"><strong>Text 1 goes here </strong><br><small style="font-size:8px">Text 2 goes here</small></div>'